# Is this the cleanest way to repeat method call in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style

The following looks like messy code, but I can't think how to make it neater. Any ideas? I want to call doSearch for values of 10, 20 and 30. If no results are returned for a value, then I want to try for the following value. Otherwise, just exit out. I know this would work, but is it the most readable way?

```
SearchResult result = doSearch("10");
if (result.getResults() == null) {
  result = doSearch("20");
  if (result.getResults() == null) {
    result = doSearch("30");
    if (result.getResults() == null) {
      // put code to deal with lack of results here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
SearchResult result = null;
for (String attempt : "10,20,30".split(","))
    if ((result = doSearch(attempt)) != null)
        break;

if (result == null) {
    // put code to deal with lack of results here
}
```

(as suggested by Marko Topolnik in the comments.)

Comment: The check `i >= attempts.length + 1` doesn't make a lot of sense as it can never evaluate to true. The code either breaks with `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` or the check returns false.

Comment: `int i; for (i = 0; i < attempts.length; i++) if ((result = doSearch(attempts[i])) != null) break; if (result == null) // put code to deal with lack of results here`

Comment: Yeah the for loop looks tidier. Thanks guys.

Comment: +1 Nice twist! If using a `static import`, you can also say `String attempt : asList("10", "20", "30")`

Comment: Ah, yeah. I would actually say that that's one of the few cases where a static import doesn't reduced readability :-)

Comment: Yeah, try importing `Integer.valueOf` for a WTF-effect :)

Answer (score 2):

You can store the search strings in a String[], then loop through the array and call doSearch().

Answer (score 1):

```
int [] searchValues = {10, 20, 30};


for(int i=0; i<searchValues.length; i++) {
   SearchResult result = doSearch(searchValues[i]);
   if (result.getResults() != null) {
       return result;
   }
}

// put code to deal with lack of results here
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like this:

```
SearchResult result = null;
for (int i=10; i<=30 && result == null; i+=10) {
    result = doSearch(i);
}
if (result == null) {
    // throw a meaningful business exception here
}
```

Since numbers are numbers, I didn't think that iterating through their String representations is a good idea.